# How to create column of ratio for different groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to calculate the ratio of basketball players shots attempts, for two different teams. Each row is one attempt. So, in the first row below, the player of team "D", shot and he made the point, so the result is equal $1$, the next shot the player missed, so the result is equal $0$. Note tha the ratio is the made shot divided by the attempts until that row.

I'm struggling on how can I calculate this ratio for all the dataframe automatically. Any hint on how can I do that?

```
dat = data.frame(team = c("D", "D", "M", "D","M", "M"),
                 result = c(1,0,0,1,1,1),
                 ratio = c(1, 1/2, 0, 2/3, 1/2, 2/3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
  mutate(ratio = cummean(result), .by = team)
#   team result     ratio
# 1    D      1 1.0000000
# 2    D      0 0.5000000
# 3    M      0 0.0000000
# 4    D      1 0.6666667
# 5    M      1 0.5000000
# 6    M      1 0.6666667
```

`cumsum(result) / row_number()` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

With base R function `ave` you can compute the wanted means.

```r
dat <- data.frame(team = c("D", "D", "M", "D","M", "M"),
                 result = c(1,0,0,1,1,1),
                 ratio = c(1, 1/2, 0, 2/3, 1/2, 2/3))

dat$ratio2 <- with(dat, ave(result, team, FUN = \(x) {
  sapply(seq_along(x), \(i) mean(x[1:i]))
}))
dat
#>   team result     ratio    ratio2
#> 1    D      1 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 2    D      0 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 3    M      0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 4    D      1 0.6666667 0.6666667
#> 5    M      1 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 6    M      1 0.6666667 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Here is another way, inspired by  [LMc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77204615/8245406).
All 3 results columns are equal.

```r
dat$ratio3 <- with(dat, ave(result, team, FUN = \(x) cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)))
dat
#>   team result     ratio    ratio2    ratio3
#> 1    D      1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 2    D      0 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 3    M      0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 4    D      1 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
#> 5    M      1 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 6    M      1 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>